# Определение пересечений элементов во время drag&drop на Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, drag-n-drop

Есть несколько блоков `div` одинакового размера, расположенных рядом по схемам 2х1, 2х2, 4х4, 5х4 и тому подобное (много камер видеонаблюдения). Нужно, захватив один блок, перетащить его на другой и `onmouseup` произвести замену камер. Но можно не дотянуть блок и отпустить его где-то на пересечении других блоков, и тут нужно определить пересечение с каким из блоков, на которые пользователь отпустил перетаскиваемый блок, наибольшее, чтобы сделать своп этих камер.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно отследить положение перетаскиваемого элемента в момент `onmouseup` по отношению к другим элементам. Анализ экранных координат элементов - единственный метод, или есть более простые и лаконичные решения (на чистом JS)?

Answer (score 0):

Есть три пути.

1. Использовать события мыши, в частности `onmouseup`. Подробнее можно посмотреть [learn.javasript](https://learn.javascript.ru/drag-and-drop)
2. Использовать нативный *Drag'n'Drop*, который появился в HTML5. Подробнее на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/187582/)
3. Использовать готовую библиотеку. Например, плагин для *jQuery* [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/). Или независимую библиотеку [dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula).

Небольшой пример с использованием событий мыши:

```js
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');

function getCoords(elem) {
  // (1)
  var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  var body = document.body;
  var docEl = document.documentElement;

  // (2)
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
  var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || docEl.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;

  // (3)
  var clientTop = docEl.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;
  var clientLeft = docEl.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

  // (4)
  var top = box.top + scrollTop - clientTop;
  var left = box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft;

  // (5)
  return {
    top: Math.round(top),
    left: Math.round(left)
  };
}
ball.onmousedown = function(e) {

  var coords = getCoords(ball);
  var shiftX = e.pageX - coords.left;
  var shiftY = e.pageY - coords.top;

  ball.style.position = 'absolute';
  document.body.appendChild(ball);
  moveAt(e);

  ball.style.zIndex = 1000; // над другими элементами

  function moveAt(e) {
    ball.style.left = e.pageX - shiftX + 'px';
    ball.style.top = e.pageY - shiftY + 'px';
  }

  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    moveAt(e);
  };

  ball.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    ball.onmouseup = null;
  };

}

ball.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};
```

```css
#ball {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ball"></div>
```